# Is AI entirely a part of Computer Science?

Tags: terminology

Both AI and Computer Science are Sciences, as I understood from Wikipedia, Computer Science is everything that has any relation to computers. And AI is commonly defined as

> Study of machines that take the prerogative of humans (creating musical pieces e.t.c

But recently, when I was reading, I read this sentence : "In Computer Science, AI is [...]"

So my question is really : Is there a part of AI studies that do not refer to Computer Science?

Comment: I would say it is, in the sense that all of the related fields @Karan touchs on are approached through the lens of computing (i.e. without technology to run sophisticated algorithms, you cannot have *artificial* intelligence, thus the study of psychology as related to AI is toward the end of reproducing psychological mechanism in a computing medium.)  Regardless, Karan's answer is quite correct.

Comment: @DukeZhou ,lets have a glimpse on generations in computing or computers.Artificial Intelligence is a general characteristics of Computers in Fifth Generation.One is trying to create a distinction between AI and Computer Science.There's no part of AI that does not refer to computer science.AI is here to describe the fundamental characters of fifth generation of computers...and if I say computers it's not only devices but cyborgs or Non-biological beings.

Comment: @DukeZhou totally agreed, there are other fields like **psychology** which would play major role as we approach [Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AI is an amalgamation of many fields, Computer Science plays a major role in imparting "Intelligence" to the machine. Following is a quote from the best selling AI book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) by
Stuart J. Russell and Peter Norvig.

> Artificial Intelligence (AI) is a big field, and this is a big book.
> We have tried to explore the full breadth of the field, which
> encompasses logic, probability, and continuous mathematics;
> perception, reasoning, learning, and action; and everything from
> microelectronic devices to robotic planetary explorers.

So, the answer to your question is yes, there are other fields that AI depends including mathematics (to optimize AI algorithms), electronic components (sensors, microprocessors, etc.), mechanical actuators (hydraulic, pneumatic, electric, etc.)

I highly recommend the book if you are looking for a starting point.

Comment: Was going to quote exactly that paragraph, so have my up vote

Comment: @Keno ,you up-vote the answer and you don't up-vote the question.Can those who up-vote the answers tell us whether the question doesn't fit or this is how the community is all about.

Comment: As @Adam893 points out, not all AI systems are electronic, so electronics isn't *necessary* for AI.  Also, since AI systems aren't necessarily robots, as Heinlein demonstrates in [The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress](http://amzn.to/2t9ma6g), creating an AI is not dependent on mechanical components.  Definitely a +1 for mathematics, though!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your perspective. As a roboticist, I view A.I. as a discipline within Robotics, which itself is a discipline of Computer Science. The difficulty in definitively labelling these fields is partly due to the massive amounts of overlap. Take robotics for example, which combines the most advanced elements of mathematics, mechanical engineering, electronics, philosophy, neurology and many more. Do bear in mind that artificial intelligence need not be hosted on silicon (i.e. computer chips), it is entirely possible to have biological artificial intelligences, 'running' on living material. Look at the works of Professor Larry Bull from the University of the West of England (my university professor):

*Bull, L. and Uroukov, I. (2008) Towards neuronal computing: simple creation of two logic functions in 3D cell cultures using multi-electrode arrays. International Journal of Unconventional Computing, 4 (2). pp. 143-154. ISSN 1548-7199 Available from: http://eprints.uwe.ac.uk/20720*

They where able to demonstrate the logic functions AND and OR using living neurons, harvested from chickens. This type of A.I. research is so different from conventional computer science that it cannot be labelled under the same field

Comment: Robotics may benefit from AI, but AI is not dependent on robotics - see, e.g., Heinlein's [The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress](http://amzn.to/2t9ma6g) for an AI that isn't a robot.  +1 for mentioning biological AI, though.